# Normalization to 3NF?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to Normalize this table to at least 3NF

> customerID | customerName | petID | petName | transID | transName | transDetails | Price

with the FD as follows

> customerID -> {customerName, petID}
>
> petID -> {petName, transID}
>
> transID -> {transName, transDetails, Price}

Now my answer to this is:

> customer(customerID, customerName) //customerID as PK
>
> pet(petID, petName, customerID) //petID as PK and customerID as FK
>
> transaction(transID, transName, transDetails, Price, petID) //transID as PK and petID as FK

I really don't understand it that much since I can't absorb the information right now because my brain is now a pulp from uni :( So am I right?

I looked at the FD much closely, should the actual 3NF be :

> pet(petID, petName, transID)
>
> customer(customerID, customerName, petID)
>
> transaction(transID, transName, transDetails, Price)

Comment: Wow there're so many similar questions on here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3nf

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is the proper relationship between customers and pets. From the functional dependencies it seams that all three entities are related 1:1, which means your first answer can work as long as the foreign keys are also unique (to prevent 1:N).

The second answer satisfies all three requirements for 3NF

- every field functionally depends on the key
- the whole key (no composite keys)
- and nothing but the key (no candidate keys)

But I would keep the foreign keys away from the pet or customer table. Each can exist on their own and we want to avoid nulls in foreign key columns. The foreign keys belong in the transaction table because a transaction is what links a pet to a customer, regardless of the desired cardinality.

Comment: Well, a customer can have more than one pet, and a pet can have more than one transaction. Since you can't have a multivalued attribute in 1NF, the second answer is incorrect, right?

Comment: The foreign keys aren't unique since customer=pet+ and pet=trans*.

Comment: that's right, the foreign key goes into the table on the "many" side of the relationship